# Textmate - how do I create a new empty file in the same folder as the current file?

Tags: textmate

With the Textmate "filesystem explorer tray" open I would like to create an empty file in the same folder as the currently open file. I cannot see a simple way of doing this barring creating a new file and then hunting through the file system in the save dialog.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the first document open in TextMate, type the following anywhere in that document (although a blank line works best):

```
mate "$TM_DIRECTORY"/mynewfile.txt
```

or even

```
mate "$(dirname "$TM_FILEPATH")"/mynewfile.txt
```

Then, highlight the text and hit **Control-r**.  If it's on its own line, you don't even need to highlight it.  Just be on the same line...  Of course, you don't need to type that all the time.  This is what we have snippets, commands and macros for!